# Regular Expression to get sections of text that start with a number in parenthesis

Tags: .net, regex

Hello I need help with Regular Expression,

I want to match each section (number and it's text - 2 groups), the text can be multi line, each section ends when another section starts (another number)  or when .END is reached or EOF.
[Demo](http://www.myregextester.com/?r=c075f0ff#sourcetab)

Expression:

```
\(\d{1,3}\) ([\s\S]*?)(\.END|\(\d{1,3}\))
```

Input text:

```
(1) some text some text
    some text some text
    some text some text  
(2) some text some textsome text

(3) some textsome text
    some textsome textsome text
(4) some text
.END
```

first group should match number (with brackets) and second group should match corresponded text.

Comment: I found out what was the cause that the regex didn't work on that site: there were some extra line breaks *after* the regex in the edit form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
\(\d{1,3}\) ([\s\S]*?)(?=(\.END|\(\d{1,3}\)))
```

Comment: Yes, I did. Sorround the whole expression in parenthesis: (...)

Comment: http://www.myregextester.com/?r=0ffe51a8
this is your expression...
when I click submit it doesn't match

Comment: It is very strange. Maybe there were some options checked somehow. I modified your first demo link and this works: http://www.myregextester.com/?r=a8cd02f0

Comment: Okay, I also see what you mean now. That is strange. I did exactly the same. Does it work for your real app?

Comment: Do you mean if it works in the website in my browser? It does. You have to test it in your app, where you need it.. Edit: Sorry, I thought you were shivesh.

Comment: please save your work at the demo site and paste the link here

Comment: worked, don't know why it didn't work for the first time, any way thank you

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
\(\d{1,3}\) ([\s\S]*?)(?=(\.END|\(\d{1,3}\)))
```

Just added the "look ahead" - I'm pretty new to regexp but this other thread seemed to help:

[Overlapping matches in Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320448/overlapping-matches-in-regex)

(Thanks for the demo site by the way - not seen that before!)

Comment: Haha! Someone who is more experienced than I am obviously got there first. Still, nice to know that it works.

Comment: Yes, I did. I saw that it did what I thought you wanted; just checking that it was what you wanted. Very cool site; bookmarked for the future!

Comment: strange, i try your regex with my example and it DOES NOT match anything

Comment: Well... it's exactly the same as True Soft's below, so I guess it works for him too. I followed your demo link, pasted in the expression. It gives me 3 groups captured, with 1 matching numbers, 2 matching text and 3 empty. Looks quite pretty with the yellow and green.  

(Did you mean "not" instead of "now" in your first comment? If not, this conversation is confusing... which it is anyway, since it works for me...)

Comment: can you please save your work and that site and paste here the link?

Comment: tank you. but i can't accept 2 answers so i accept the first one.