# C# Regular Expression -- can a character be matched more than once in a single 'Match' call?

Tags: c#, expression

I think the best way to ask this question is to provide an example.

I have a string:

```
string line = "12345";
 string pattern = "[0-9]{4}";
 MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(line, pattern);
```

This will return ONE match in the collection: "1234". BUT, is there a way to get it to return "1234" AND "2345"? So I want the regular expression to not skip characters that have been already been matched.

I'm very new to regular expressions so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overlapping matches in Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320448/overlapping-matches-in-regex)

Comment: Yup, missed that somehow. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"(?=(\d{4}))" will not only match both substrings, they'll tell you so; you can access the values of the matched substrings using Match.Groups[1] for each match.

Answer (score 1):

Change the expression to:

```
 (?=\d{4})
```

Comment: This will return the correct number of matches, but not their content. Adding another set of parenthesis around the `\d{4}` ought to do it; you can then access the content via Groups[1] on each match.