# Returning overlapping regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

Is there a regular expression that will capture all instances of an expression, regardless of whether or not they overlap?

E.g. in `/abc/def/ghi` if I want to capture all strings beginning with `/`. The regex `(/.*)` only returns the entire string, but I'd want it to match on `/def/ghi` and `/ghi` as well.

Comment: Interesting subject. Just to be sure, matching just `/abc`, `/def` and `/ghi` isn't what you are looking for, is it?

Comment: @Arjan no, it's not. That would be too easy!

Comment: I find that `(?=(/.*))` does the trick, see also [Overlapping matches][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/320448/653295

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, match an empty string and place a look-ahead after it that captures `/.*` in a capturing group:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?=(/.*))").matcher("/abc/def/ghi");
while(m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

would print:

```
/abc/def/ghi
/def/ghi
/ghi
```