# Overlapping regular expression

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760162/returning-overlapping-regular-expressions). However I didn't get it working:

I have a string like "my_token_string" and need a regex to return the tokens "my_", "_token_", and "_string".

Please note that I am not able to change the java-code because it's part of another software. The only thing I can do is specify the pattern and the group to capture :-)

This is what I have tested:

```
String p = "(?=(_[^_]*_?))";
int group = 1;
String test = "my_token_string";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(p).matcher(test);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(group));
}
```

But of course this returns only the tokens "_token_" and "_string".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with `"(?=((^|_).+?(_|$)))"`. As group number use `1`.

It will let token start with `_` or beginning of input (`^`) and end it with `_` or end of input (`$`). Instead of `.+?` you can use `[^_]+` but I prefer this version.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with RegEx: `(?=((?:_|^)[^_]*+(?:_|$)))`
Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/tB0bZ4

Comment: +1 anyway there is no need for non-capturing groups since they are inside group that OP will use, not before it.