# Regex - is it possible to find overlaping groups?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to regex and just want to know if its possible to find "overlaping" groups in the matches.

assume the following string:

> 20122 0029431 7094 0111 5890

I want now all matches which are: 4number+space+4number+space+4number

What I tried is this: `[0-9]{4}[\s][0-9]{4}[\s][0-9]{4}`

But this just gave me: 9431 7094 0111

What I want are these matches:

- 9431 7094 0111
- 7094 0111 5890

is this possible with regex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overlapping matches in Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320448/overlapping-matches-in-regex)

Comment: @TimPietzcker thanks, I mismatched the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you use [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in combination with [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(?=(\d{4}\s\d{4}\s\d{4}))");
Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    resultList.Add(matchResult.Groups[1].Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```