# JavaScript: detection of regular expression in source code

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to parse JavaScript  source code and match all regular expressions with the help of a regular expression :).
First I tried this regular expression:

```
(?:\/.*\/)
```

But it does not work if the regular expression contains slash, like in the next source code

```
while (line.match(/[+*/]/))
        line = line.replace(/([+*/])\s(\d+)\s(\d+)/, function (s, op, a, b) {
            return operators[op](+a, +b);
        });
```

I don`t know how to keep all possibilities in one regular expression.
Is there any way to match a regular expression in javascript source code using regular expressions?

Comment: Not a good idea. JavaScript syntax is way too complex. Use a full-blown parser to parse JS code, [such are freely available](http://esprima.org/)

Comment: The reason your pattern didn't work is because `(?:)` means do not match.

Comment: @JoeHabadas: No. It means "match, but don't capture". Your regex matches exactly the same as his.

Comment: Well, that's what I meant, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, what would I use to "capture, but don't match"?

Comment: @JoeHabadas: Very good question! You could use a capturing group within a lookahead assertion: `(?=(foo))` used on the string `"foo"` would have the match result `""`, and group 1 would contain `"foo"`. This is a contrived example, of course, but the feature itself is very useful, for example when looking for overlapping matches, as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326284/regex-is-it-possible-to-find-overlaping-groups/11326404#11326404).

Comment: @JoeHabadas: It's a normal positive lookahead assertion, yes, the only twist being that it also contains a capturing group. Nothing special really.