# Regular Expression for finding palindromes behaving strange

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a program which finds palindromes (words which are the same from start to end and end to start like `anna`).

But it should also work for multiple words `car a rac` and inside sentences `asdcar a racbnm`.

I wrote a regular expression to find the span of a start of a palindrome:

```
([a-z])(\s*)[a-z]?(\\2)(\\1)
```

It finds a letter then there can be spaces, then there can be another letter, spaces again, and the first letter again.

It works fine but for the string `xxxxx` it behaves strange:

```
import re
p = re.compile('([a-z])(\s*)[a-z]?(\\2)(\\1)')
finds = p.finditer('xxxxx')
for m in finds:
    print m.span()
```

output

```
(0, 3)
(3, 5)
```

It doesn't find the one I'm searching for: `(1, 4)`

What´s wrong with my re?

Edit: it should just find the start of the palindrome. The algorithm will do the rest.

Comment: you 'solved ' a problem using a RegEx - now you have two problems!

Comment: I'm inclined to say that regular expressions aren't a good way to search for palindromes as palindromes aren't a regular language. It doesn't mean it can't be done (backreferences allow recognizing of many non-regular languages) but it could be done with less hassle and probably more efficiently as well using other tools.

Comment: You are matching `<letter> - <zero or more spaces> - <optional letter> - <the exact number of spaces from before> - <the first letter>`. That first matches at position 0, but regular expressions never match overlapping regions.

Comment: thanks Martjin i think this is the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression cannot match overlapping regions (you'd need to play with [look-arounds with capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320448/overlapping-matches-in-regex) to do that).

The expression matches the first three `x` characters first; it matches:

- one character (group 1), zero spaces (group 2), an optional character (the `?` is greedy), the zero spaces from group 2, the one character from group 1.

The second match then *has* to start after that; the two `xx` characters match because the `[a-z]?` pattern is optional.

You cannot create a regular expression to match palindromes in general (at least not with the Python `re` engine), as there is no facility to match an arbitrary-width previous group in reverse.

Comment: "Regular" expressions *can* match overlapping regions (or at least find overlapping matches): http://stackoverflow.com/q/11326284/20670, and can even find palindromes if the engine is sufficiently sophisticated (Python's isn't, though). For example, PHP can use `/^(?:(.)(?=.*(\1(?(2)\2|))$))*.?\2?$/` to detect palindromes: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3746487/20670

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Right, I was not familiar with any engine that could; the PHP engine looks sufficiently painful..

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I had not yet learned about the look-around-with-capturing-group tricks; added to my regex playbook. Updated the answer with your references, thanks.