# Finding all possible substrings within a string. Python Regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to find all possible substrings inside a string with the following requirement: The substring starts with N, the next letter is anything but  P, and the next letter is S or T

With the test string `"NNSTL"`,  I would like to get as results `"NNS" and "NST"`

Is this possible with Regex?

Comment: Check this out my friend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030428/match-regex-pattern-within-pattern and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp/11430936#11430936

Hope it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
N[^P\W\d_][ST]
```

The first character is N, the next character is none of (^) P, a non-letter (\W), a digit (\d) or underscore (_). The last letter is either S or T. I'm assuming the second character must be a letter.

EDIT

The above regex will only match the *first* instance in the string `"NNSTL"` because it will then start the next potential match at position 3: `"TL"`. If you truly want both results at the same time use the following:

```
(?=(N[^P\W\d_][ST])).
```

The substring will be in group 1 instead of the whole pattern match which will only be the first character.

Comment: @rodrigovz Cool! Want to mark it as the right answer?

Comment: There should be a big tick to the left of each answer. Click the one next to mine! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the re module:

```
import re
```

Here's a possible search string:

```
my_txt = 'NfT foo NxS bar baz NPT'
```

So we use the regular expression that first looks for an N, any character other than a P, and a character that is either an S or a T.

```
regex = 'N[^P][ST]'
```

and using `re.findall`:

```
found = re.findall(regex, my_txt)
```

and found returns:

```
['NfT', 'NxS']
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The regex snippet is: `"N[^P][ST]"`

Plug it in to any regex module methods from here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Explanation:

- `N` matches a literal "N".
- `[^P]` is a set, where the caret ("^") denotes inverse (so, it matches anything not in the set.
- `[ST]` is another set, where it matches either an "S" or a "T".

Comment: ... except if you actually run this, it returns `['NNS']` (no "NST").

Comment: Right. CJ Dennis seems to have the correct answer using lookahead assertion.