# Count specific groups of letters in python without excluding them

Tags: python, count

i'm trying to find a way to have python count a specific subset of a string that is different from the usual `str.count("X")`

Here is my general example. My variable is `dna="AAAAA"`
My goal is to recognize each set of "AA" that exist in the string.
When I run `dna.count("AA")`I get the predictable result of 2 when I print.

However, the result I am looking for is an output of 4. Here is an image to show visually what I am saying. (I would insert the image, but I do not have the 10 reputation required, so I must post a link) https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/16IGo3hIstcNEqVid8BI6uj09KX4MWWAzSuQcu8AjSu0/edit?usp=sharing

I have been unable to find a satisfactory solution to this problem elsewhere. Probably because i'm not sure what to call my problem. EDIT: I was informed this is counting overlapping substrings.

The matter becomes more complicated, as the full program will not have a single repeated letter in the string, but rather 4 letters (ATCG) repeated at random for undetermined lengths. Here is an example `dna="AtcGTgaTgctagcg"`I would need the script to out put how many pairs of AT, TC,CG,TG, etc. that exist. While moving one letter incrementally to the right.

Thank you.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp

Answer (score 1):

For the easiest case, pairs:

```
dna = 'AtcGTgaTgctagcg'.upper()
from collections import Counter
for (a, b), ctr in Counter(zip(dna, dna[1:])).items():
    print(a + b, ctr)
```

Prints:

```
CT 1
TC 1
TA 1
GA 1
AG 1
CG 2
GC 2
GT 1
AT 2
TG 2
```

For the more general case of an arbitrary chosen length:

```
dna = 'AtcGTgaTgctagcg'.upper()
length = 2

from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(dna[i:i+length] for i in range(len(dna) - length + 1))

for string, count in counts.items():
    print(string, count)
```

And one that counts every substring, since you said "undetermined lengths":

```
dna = 'AtcGTgaTgctagcg'.upper()

from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(dna[i:j+1] for j in range(len(dna)) for i in range(j+1))

for string, count in counts.items():
    print(string, count)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest algorithm using slices:

```
checks = ['AA']
string = 'AAAAA'
before = string[0:1]
for letter in string[1:]:
   if before + letter in checks:
     print "found = " + checks[checks.index(before+letter)]
    before = letter
```

output:

```
found AA
found AA
found AA
found AA
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer linked to above in the comments ([How to find overlapping matches with a regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp)) is probably the most efficient way to do this.

That said, there's also nothing wrong with a generator expression and a `collections.Counter` in this situation, in my opinion.

```
 seq_length = 2
 string = "atctatcta"
 counts = collections.Counter(a[i:i + seq_length] for i in range(len(string) - seq_length)

 print counts  # Counter({'ct': 2, 'at': 2, 'tc': 2, 'ta': 1})
 print counts["ct"]  # 2
 print counts["ta"]  # 1
```

`collections.Counter` takes an iterable (e.g. a generator expression) and returns the frequency of each of the items in the sequence as a `dict`-like mapping. The generator expression here uses a little indexing logic to generate each of the `seq_length` substrings lazily.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

dnaseq = 'AtcGTgaTgctagcg'
dnaseq_upper = dnaseq.upper()
it1 = iter(dnaseq_upper)
it2 = iter(dnaseq_upper)
next(it2)
adjacent_pairs_iterator = (''.join(pair) for pair in zip(it1, it2))
cntr = Counter(adjacent_pairs_iterator)
output_generator = ('{}: {}'.format(ss, cnt) for ss, cnt in cntr.items())
print(*output_generator, sep='\n')
```

This is a low-memory solution using iterators. The memory bottleneck here will be your `Counter` object which is hard to avoid using.

This outputs:

```
GT: 1
TA: 1
TC: 1
CT: 1
GA: 1
TG: 2
CG: 2
AG: 1
AT: 2
GC: 2
```

This is written to work in Python 3.x by the way, so if you're in Python 2.x, you'll have to be careful. `zip` will have to be changed into `itertools.izip`, `cntr.items` will have to be changed into `cntr.iteritems`, the print function will not work, and perhaps other things as well.