# python - how to get overlapping text matches in regex

Tags: python, regex, overlapping-matches

I am using the following to get all matches including overlapping as per [recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches) on [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp) threads:

```
[(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.findall(t,s,overlapped = True)]
```

where t is a subset of s. However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: findall() got an unexpected keyword argument 'overlapped.'
```

What am I doing wrong/is overlapped an outdated flag/how would you do it? All help is much appreciated.

Comment: what are you trying to match? Also  `overlapped=True` is part of the external lib `regex` which will not work with the python `re` lib

Comment: The post referrers to a new version of the regex module. You have to install it first.

Comment: Also the first answer on the first thread you linked seems like it does what you want without any additional libraries.

Comment: Try `import regex as re`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Cunningham and Klaus, the flag I'm referring to comes from a different package that is not re.

I figured out a solution without downloading an external package, though, using lookahead:

```
[(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer('(?='+t+')',s)]
```

When s = 'GATATATGCATATACTT' and t = 'ATAT', you get [(1, 1), (3, 3), (9, 9)]. I don't need to return the text in the match, just the indices, so it doesn't matter if it matches ['','',''].

Comment: Regex can be tailored to do different overlapping. Do you understand how it works ?

Comment: do you mean the import package regex or re, which I am using here? I understand how to edit packages, yes.

Comment: Not the package. I mean why this `(?=ATAT)` gets overlaps.

Comment: Do you really want  `[(1, 1), (3, 3), (9, 9)]` as the output?

Comment: @sln It works because the expression actually matches the '', each of which are non-overlapping.

Comment: no, @PadraicCunningham in my code i tossed the `m.end(0)` and used `' '.join(comprehension)`

Comment: @sln for further clarification it doesn't actually match what's inside the (?=pattern) because that's the lookahead function in re.

Comment: Actually it does match `(?=pattern)`, it just doesn't consume it. So you wouldn't think the match position changes between matches, but it does, it advances 1 character position before the next match starts. This is so there is not an infinite loop.Its called _bump along_. I think all engines do this. A safer approach is to force it along via `(?=pattern).`

Comment: @sln i think my understanding was there, but that's certainly a better way to describe what's going on. thanks for the in-depth explanation.