# Overlapping matches in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible in JavaScript to find a nested match with an arbitrary regular expression (I found solutions only for spacial regex cases - not arbitrary)? For example, if I have the text `"555666"`, and I try matching with the regex `5.*6` , I always get 1 match byt this code

```js
let m = "555666".match(/5.*6/);

console.log(m)
```

but the desired output for me is get all matches

```
['56', '556', '5556', '566', '5666', ...]
```

Second example of regexp: `a?.b|a.*c` input string `"aaabbbcaccdddedeee"` and desired output

```
['ab', 'bb','aaabbbc',....]
```

I look for solution which works for arbitrary regexp - how I can do it in JS?

Comment: Generate an array of all substrings of the string, and modify the regex to be `/^...$/`, then use [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) on each substring.

Comment: Please be aware of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): the task at hand might be solved using different methods, and forcing a regular expression into it is among the least optimal options.

Comment: *"get all matches"*: there are no multiple interpretations of a regex. In your example, 56 is not a valid match, because `.*` is greedy.

Comment: I have already answered this question. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34964708/3832970). Mark Reed [also provided a JS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34965064/3832970).

Comment: I just posted an answer that allows lazy iteration of substring matches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56657282/1541563).

Comment: If you had branch reset `https://regex101.com/r/A5T2pB/1`