# JavaScript RegEx don't stop on the first match

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match many occurances of regex.

My text is:

```
aaaHello WorldaaaSomethingaaaAnother thingaaaSame thing
```

And I want to match `aaaHello WorldaaaSomethingaaa`, not `aaaHello Worldaaa` and `aaaAnother thingaaa`

I tried to write a regex like that:

```
/aaa.*?aaa/g
```

It's enough to take all possibilities of pattern like `aaaHello Worldaaa`, `aaaHello WorldaaaSomethingaaa`, `aaaHello WorldaaaSomethingaaaAnother thignaaa`... And so on... I can process them on the loop. I just want to take all occurances.

But I couldn't get what I want.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew maybe you chose the wrong question while flagging as duplicate. That's about ruby

Comment: No, it is  correct. The question has both Ruby and JS tags and solutions. See https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/726mfL9b/ demo based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/56657282/3832970 answer, or https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/726mfL9b/2/ demo based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/34964708/3832970 answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would have answered with a more modern approach, using the new entry method `matchAll`, which it's getting a decent support nowadays. I don't know if it would be meaningful also in the linked question

Comment: Please add it there. Why not?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 's jsfiddle samples are enough for me. Thank you.