# Multiple hits from the same word

Tags: python, regex

I have a string and I want to extract matches from it using regex.
The string is as follows:

```
you and he and she and me
```

And my regex is (so far):

```
(\w+) and (\w+)
```

What I want is it should give this result:

```
(you, he), (he, she), (she, me)
```

but current result just include 2 matches, which are

```
(you, he), (she, me)
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is [overlapping regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp).

This is how you do it:

```
import re                                                                       

s = "you and he and she and me"                                                 

print re.findall(r'(?=\b(\w+) and (\w+)\b)', s)
```

In fact it does such a good job looking for overlaps, you'll need the `\b`'s I added to indicate you want to match the word boundaries.  Otherwise you get:

```
[('you', 'he'), ('ou', 'he'), ('u', 'he'), ('he', 'she'), ('e', 'she'), ('she', 'me'), ('he', 'me'), ('e', 'me')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the zero width positive lookahead like:

```
(?=(?:^|\s)(\w+)\s+and\s+(\w+))
```

- The zero width lookahead pattern starts with `(?=` and ends in last `)`
- `(?:^|\s)` is a non-captured group, ensuring the desired patterns are at the start or followed by whitespace
- `(\w+)\s+and\s+(\w+)`, gets out desired pattern with first and second captured groups

**Example:**

```
In [11]: s = 'you and he and she and me'

In [12]: re.findall(r'(?=(?:^|\s)(\w+)\s+and\s+(\w+))', s)
Out[12]: [('you', 'he'), ('he', 'she'), ('she', 'me')]
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed it, what you're looking for is called overlapping matches.
With the newer [**`regex` module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), you could stick to your initial approach and apply another flag:

```
import regex as re

string = "you and he and she and me"
rx = r'\b(\w+) and (\w+)\b'

matches = re.findall(rx, string, overlapped=True)
print matches
# [('you', 'he'), ('he', 'she'), ('she', 'me')]
```

Hint: you'll need word boundaries on top (`\b`), otherwise you'll get unexpected results.