# How to: Overlapping match

Tags: python, regex

Lets say we have this:

```
A2 A1 B.         #1

A1 B.            #2

A3 A1 A8 B.      #3
```

How would I go about if I want:

1. To match: `A2 A1 B.` and `A1 B.`
2. To match: `A1 B.`
3. To match: `A3 A1 A8 B.` and `A1 A8 B.` and `A8 B.`

So far I've got this regex:

```
A\d\s(.*\.)
```

But it won't match subsets of code that's already been matched (I'm matching using `re.finditer`)/  My guess is that `re.finditer` is doing just as its supposed to, and I'm just trying to force it into doing stupid stuff.

[Playground](https://regex101.com/r/ADQwFG/36)

Comment: One question - why do you expect `B.` to match `A\d\s(.*\.)`?

Comment: Are you expecting 1,2, and 3 to be capturing groups?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen ops, typo. Fixing it now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find overlapping matches with a regexp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh not necessarily. I just need to be able to distinguish `A2 A1 B.` from `A1 B.` etc. I need to perform different operation on them in the code after the regex is done.

Comment: do you need regex? could you just make a list of substrings and with spit and join?

Comment: @depperm the pattern in the actual code is a bit more complicated than the example. So regex would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookahead for this and capture values inside the lookahead:

```
regex = r"(?=((?:A\d+\s+)+B\.))"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/50XxeL/1)

**RegEx Description:**

```
(?=               # start lookahead
   (              # start capturing group #1
      (?:         # start non-capturing group
         A\d+\s+  # match A followed by 1 or more digit followed by 1 or more whitespace
      )           # end non-capturing group
      +B\.        # match B and literal DOT
   )              # end capture group #1
)                 # end lookahead
```

**Code:**

```
>>> regex = r"(?=((?:A\d+\s+)+B\.))"

>>> print re.findall(regex, 'A2 A1 B.')
['A2 A1 B.', 'A1 B.']

>>> print re.findall(regex, 'A1 B.')
['A1 B.']

>>> print re.findall(regex, 'A3 A1 A8 B.')
['A3 A1 A8 B.', 'A1 A8 B.', 'A8 B.']
```