# Python re findall multiple occurrences allowing same characters

Tags: python

```
import re
print(len(re.findall('ANA', 'BANANA')))
```

This outputs 1, but I want to count matches using characters inclusively, so the output should be 2. Can this be done using re findall?

Comment: no, you'll have to write code to change the anchor point iteratively. What you want are overlapping matches, but the methods of the `re` module only find non-overlapping matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with the currently standard `re` module. However, as pointed out in other threads, you could use the newer `regex` module which offers an `overlapped` flag:

```
import regex
print(len(regex.findall('ANA', 'BANANA', overlapped=True)))
```

Information on `regex` module can be found here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

You will likely have to install it as:

```
pip install regex
```

The other threads mentioned: [How to find overlapping matches with a regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp)
and
[Python regex find all overlapping matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches)