# Return all overlapping patterns using re.findall() in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, findall

Thank you in advance for reading.

I have a string:

```
A = "a levels"
```

I want to match all of the following possible variations of A level:

```
Pattern = r"a level|a levels"
```

(The form of this pattern is set, I cannot change it.)
Following the search, I desire to get:

```
["a level","a levels"]
```

I use findall as follows:

```
B = re.findall(Pattern,A)
```

and get:

```
B = "a level"
```

re.findall only matches the first term and ignores the second overlapping term.

Per: [Python regex find all overlapping matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches) I tried using:

```
B = re.findall(Pattern,A,overlapped = True)
```

and get the following error:

```
TypeError: findall() got an unexpected keyword argument 'overlapped'
```

Obviously `overlapped` doesn't exist as a keyword argument any more...

I then looked at this question: [Python regex find all overlapping matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches) and tried:

```
C = re.finditer(Pattern,A)
results = match.group()

results = "a level"
```

So no better.

How can I get the output I desire?

Relevant qu: [How to find overlapping matches with a regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp)

Comment: You may only match overlapping strings at different indices.

Comment: I am not sure if its possible to achieve what you want but the overlapped error can be resolved via `pip install regex` and then `import regex as re`
regex is newer version of regex module for python.

Comment: @saurabhbaid. Unfortunately, the `overlapped` option in `regex` will not resolve the problem here, as it does not work with alternation.

Comment: I did not know there was a separate re and regex module. Thank you for the information. @ekhumoro Thanks for telling me the word for what I was trying to convey (seriously - I was a bit wordy without it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all every possible `Pattern` is similar to what you've shown, this might work for you:

```
B=[b for pat in Pattern.split('|') for b in re.findall(pat, A)]
```

Of course, this doesn't generalize beyond `Pattern` being a set of simple alternatives.

Comment: Thank you Rob. So it looks like you split the string by `|` and then carry out `.findall` on each of the split elements if I understand correctly? The funny thing is, I started with a version of Pattern that looked like `Pattern = ["a level", "a levels"...]` and converted it to `Pattern = "a level | a levels..."` Maybe I can get rid of that, and then implement only the `findall` part of your answer... When all is together, I will see which way is faster and pick that. Thanks for the help :)