# php regex find substring in substring

Tags: php, regex

I am still playing around for one project with matching words.

Let assume that I have a given string, say ***maxmuster*** . Then I want to mark *this* part of my random word ***maxs*** which are in ***maxmuster*** in the proper order, like the letters are.

I wil give some examples and then I tell what I already did. Lets keep the string ***maxmuster***. The bold part is the matched one by regex (best would be in php, however could be python, bash, javascript,...)

**max**s

My**maxmu**is

Le**mu**

**muster**

Of course also **m**, **u**, ... will be matched then. I know that, I am going to fix that later. However, the solution, I though, should not so difficult, so I try to divide the word in groups like this:

```
/(maxmuster)?|(maxmuste)?|(maxmust)?|(maxmus)?|(maxmu)?|(maxm)?|(max)?|(ma)?|(m)?/gui
```

But then I forgot of course the other combinations, like:

`(axmuster)(xmus)` and so on. Did I really have to do that, or exist there a simple regex trick, to solve this question, like I explained above?

Thank you very much

Comment: `maxs` and `muster` should be matched? I would have thought `m` is required, then `ma`, `max`, `maxm`, etc. Not an error that will cause false positives but `(ma)?|(ma)?` is a duplicate.

Comment: This is not regex only task. Though you can use regex+programming to solve this.

Comment: This matches single characters, which is not what @Allan Karlson wants, as far as I understand. My first thought was `(m?a?x?m?u?s?t?e?r?)`, but that matches `mtr`, for example.

Comment: yes exactly, that does not work, you understand me right :). @chris85, sorry that was a typo wrong from my site, I wanted to write only on time "(ma)?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need string intersection. If you don't mind **non regex idea**, have a look in Wikibooks [**Algorithm Implementation/Strings/Longest common substring**](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#PHP) PHP section.

```
foreach(["maxs", "Mymaxmuis", "Lemu", "muster"] AS $str)
  echo get_longest_common_subsequence($str, "maxmuster") . "\n";
```

> max
>   maxmu
>   mu
>   muster

[See this PHP demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##nVVRb9owEH4mv@KEkEpUthZeKZuqatImdVPVTtoDq5BJL9jMsZntlLGV387OTkgItBVbHmLH/nzf3Xfny4IvNpuL9zcfb6IozVXihFYwQzeRWs3Qukmis0yric2nFn/mqBLsdqwzQs0m/R5sp4M4@hO1qo2JRDVzHEZAKzSvj8TDGjZ4ETYIMIMuNwqqZwQnJ7QetUQK3UOu0QjO4ekJDs37nThqkYetszP4osGKTEhmhBNoabEkKgmJYu1ZOi9LQK4wY9iqGwd/yOgnRcaYFL8RHEe4ursuEOA0MGvzLKwbpFUEte/BEVSTVEjZPa8l3wbee2F/UO2fx4WbHSIMLNa7SZqE1VQbUlOEb6Dx4oDBL5@elgIW8HkJn@/ABzV8HuAB78W54pj8AHxEswKKcCoUC3WmU0g4MyxxaHweQmLJmtNSL9HUOR53xH0c8vjM7mDcmd/Hnq8g9IxfOdpCa58Ny0h@oWCqqRqKU4GuKCSxUzrzqlgqayG77sQGS6kw1tVO98BqEH4zkciMXIFW9OrXCPCZLey8kmQfn4@CVO0PA3od3igtPueKVrhHQYPjTBXhhgghNToL3wuDj0Lntj7yLw69joI30PfIMMJp0/1a4yOY3kGjPvdTcIsZZtMQprB0pUJk5YFtOM3yPoJ0WJn/JhZUL2pVi2XQ5tLZ0najF5WNqDx6qR68MwpSJiXNjM5n3N9703BZ4RIemczxfwXylXmsRJU0ZTF0bdwMhG4SUTjTaOY@m00VKaG9PdKdBK/L@/2BypRgvulZrnP5AFOqQnReBOpISy4STtcElpQ2Jg2yhxVdx23DJPV0FIyty2Z6W/gYwhAUA/WJjLmE@1a536vX9N/SZDLh3XE7Y79suwftzyuaZbkIH9eY5X7Mckul376Hy7vQs@IIABOuj/nd@ePeYrAQw1tof1ftYRRtNn8B) (caseless comparison).

---

If you need a **regex idea**, I would join both strings with space and use a pattern like [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xYFNIE/1/).

```
(?=(\w+)(?=\w* \w*?\1))\w
```

It will [capture inside a lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp) at each position before a word character in the first string the longest substring that also matches the second string. Then by PHP matches of the first group need to be sorted by length and the longest match will be returned. See the [PHP demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##hVBNa8MwDL37VwgTiL1lTdNr15XddtigsGMSQhrcJhDbrT/IRulvz2TTbey0g5H09PwkvVN/mufH7e5lR8jBq84NWsFRuGbU6iisazotpVaN9Xsrzl6oTrBkKjaUZpBMK4ycXAhA4gLZOgMbOBlxbM5eu0jN0jzlCwp08QdfRXxN8O9wYLElW9f1TTuOLM3ZdsOq6Z5jrKY7wLetCs6rKR/S7Hcapto7Dk@w5KgUNgHwVhvHQqMs6gy@z2JJi/Q9hwsY4bxRgAKjQByxh5@i5Wu44mJB6ca7SZXLOsBXciVoljai7XpWUtl@WHSDvn1iJv0Qi1chfYjSWycMreH5HRIcEbYUXa//9TgeR6NiVOCwAFopio7N8xc).

```
function get_longest_common_subsequence($w1="", $w2="")
{
  $test_str = preg_quote($w1,'/')." ".preg_quote($w2,'/');

  if(preg_match_all('/(?=(\w+)(?=\w* \w*?\1))\w/i', $test_str, $out) > 0)
  {
    usort($out[1], function($a, $b) { return strlen($b) - strlen($a); });
    return $out[1][0];
  }
}
```

Comment: wow that looks great, that is exactly what it should do, thank you very much!

Comment: ok I just see, but I guess I should fix that, that I have to make it somehow case insensitive.

Comment: You're welcome @AllanKarlson might want to use `strtolower` on all the strings before comparing if desired.

Comment: Yes I just tested it but then I have to convert the uppercase letter back. I know there is something with `strtoupper()`. I hope it works then but however the words are matched that is the important part :D

Comment: @AllanKarlson I think you can do the comparsion case insensitive by switching `if ($string_1[$i] === $string_2[$j])` to eg `if (strtolower($string_1[$i]) === strtolower($string_2[$j]))` just play around a bit :) good luck

Comment: @AllanKarlson Just [another demo](https://eval.in/784024) with caseless comparison.

Comment: @AllanKarlson Years later - while writing an answer to another question - I got a simple regex idea and wonder if that also would work. However I updated my answer and added it :)

Comment: Great, this look very nice. Yes, years later, this project is solved, however I will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Using Regular Expressions:

```
longestSubstring(['Mymaxmuis', 'axmuis', 'muster'], buildRegexFrom('maxmuster'));
```

[**Full snippet**](https://3v4l.org/7GOk3)

---

Using below regex you are able to match all true sub-strings of string `maxmuster`:

```
(?|((?:
    m(?=a)
    |(?<=m)a
    |a(?=x)
    |(?<=a)x
    |x(?=m)
    |(?<=x)m
    |m(?=u)
    |(?<=m)u
    |u(?=s)
    |(?<=u)s
    |s(?=t)
    |(?<=s)t
    |t(?=e)
    |(?<=t)e
    |e(?=r)
    |(?<=e)r
)+)|([maxmuster]))
```

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/N2UQ6X/1)**

You have to cook such a regex from a word like `maxmuster` so you need a function to call it:

```
function buildRegexFrom(string $word): string {
    // Split word to letters
    $letters = str_split($word);
    // Creating all side of alternations in our regex
    foreach ($letters as $key => $letter)
        if (end($letters) != $letter)
            $regex[] = "$letter(?={$letters[$key + 1]})|(?<=$letter){$letters[$key + 1]}";
    // Return whole cooked pattern
    return "~(?|((?>".implode('|', $regex).")+)|([$word]))~i";
}
```

To return longest match you need to sort results according to matches length from longest to shortest. It means writing another piece of code for it:

```
function longestSubstring(array $array, string $regex): array {
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        preg_match_all($regex, $value, $matches);
        usort($matches[1], function($a, $b) {
            return strlen($b) <=> strlen($a);
        });
        // Store longest match being sorted
        $substrings[] = $matches[1][0];
    }

    return $substrings;
}
```

Putting all things together:

```
print_r(longestSubstring(['Mymaxmuis', 'axmuis', 'muster'], buildRegexFrom('maxmuster')));
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => maxmu
    [1] => axmu
    [2] => muster
)
```

**[PHP live demo](https://3v4l.org/7GOk3)**

Comment: I'd appreciate to know what was the reason for downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this problem using regex.

```
<?php
$subject="maxmuster";
$str="Lemu";

$comb=str_split($subject); // Split into single characters.
$len=strlen($subject);

for ($i=2; $i<=$len; $i++){
    for($start=0; $start<$len; $start++){
        $temp="";
        $inc=$start;
        for($j=0; $j<$i; $j++){
            $temp=$temp.$subject[$inc];
            $inc++;
        }
        array_push($comb,$temp);
    }
}

echo "Matches are:\n";
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($comb); $i++){
    $pattern = "/".$comb[$i]."/";
    if(preg_match($pattern,$str, $matches)){
        print_r($matches);  
    };
}
?>
```

And here is an **[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/28yPVh)**.

Comment: Although it's executing on Ideone it's throwing an `Uninitialized string offset: 9` on my localhost. Not able to figure out why.

Comment: thanks but I also habe a offset error, however I will look into that.

Comment: @AllanKarlson: I am getting the same. But it works fine on Ideone. If you correct it let me know.