# How to iterate over a string in groups of n characters instead of one character at a time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose -

```
string = "abcdefgh"
```

If I do -

```
for i in string:
    print (i)
```

I get -

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

What I want is something like -

```
ab
bc
cd
de
ef
fg
```

Or in any other grouping we specify. Is it possible to make a function for this keeping in mind the grouping we require? Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> for i, j in zip(string, string[1:]):
...     print(i+j)
... 
ab
bc
cd
de
ef
fg
gh
```

As a function:

```
def func(seq, n):
    return [''.join(item) for item in zip(*[seq[n:] for n in range(n)])]
```

Example:

```
>>> for item in func("abcdefgh", 3):
...     print(item)
... 
abc
bcd
cde
def
efg
fgh
```

Answer (score 1):

if `s` is the name of your string, this comprehension will do what you want:

`[s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s) - 1)]`

Using this, you can easily print the strings on separate lines:

```
for substr in [s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s) -1)]:
  print substr
```

It can be generalised fairly easily:

```
def subgroups(s, n):
    return [s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s) - 1)]
```

(and this function can similarly be used to print the resulting substrings in any fashion you like)

Comment: This is not what OP wants

Comment: This returns `['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh']`, which does not include the overlaps.

Comment: Fair enough. Fixed.

Comment: This returns `h` at the end

Comment: @TerryA, it returns `['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef', 'fg', 'gh']`, if the final value isn't required (although I imagine this might be a typo on OPs part - since their original output is wrong), you can just change the range to `len(s) - 2`.

Comment: @Darkstarone I suspect that TerryA was looking at a prior edit. I'd missed the final subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
string = "abcdefgh"

i = 0
while i < len(string) - 1:
    print(string[i]+string[i+1])
    i += 1
```

Result:

```
ab
bc
cd
de
ef
fg
gh
```

If you don't want `gh` (it's missing in your example), change the while loop to: `while i < len(string) - 2:`.

Also another way to do (which hasn't been posted), is via regex:

```
import re

print("\n".join(re.findall(r'(?=(\w\w))', 'abcdefgh')))
```

The `(?=)` (lookahead assertion), allows regex patterns to overlap.

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
def splittext(text, split_by):
    '''the regex will take a string and create groupings of n-characters plus a final grouping of any remainder. if no remainder is desired, the |.+ can be removed''' 
    return re.findall(r".{%d}|.+" % split_by, text)

ret = splittext("HELLOWORLD!", 2)
print "\n".join(ret)
```

some sample output

```
>>> re.findall(r".{2}",a)
['HE', 'LL', 'OW', 'OR', 'LD']
>>> re.findall(r".{2}|.{1}",a)
['HE', 'LL', 'OW', 'OR', 'LD', '!']
>>> re.findall(r".{2}|.*",a)
['HE', 'LL', 'OW', 'OR', 'LD', '!', '']
>>> re.findall(r".{2}|.+",a)
['HE', 'LL', 'OW', 'OR', 'LD', '!']
>>> print "\n".join(_)
HE
LL
OW
OR
LD
!
>>>
```

Comment: Clever. Unfortunately, clever is usually a sign of a bad idea.

Comment: Your initial example was almost correct, you just needed to add `overlapped=True`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18966698/1695437). Alternatively, you could use a lookahead assertion (`(?=)`).

Comment: @Darkstarone the .+ will pull any remainder ... wasn't sure if the OP wanted only full pairs or pairs + remainder