# Find all strings starting and ending with given substring in a string using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have given a string

> ATGCCAGGCTAGCTTATTTAA

and I have  to find out all substrings in string which starts with ATG and end with either of TAA, TAG, TGA.

Here is what I am doing:

```py
seq="ATGCCAGGCTAGCTTATTTAA"
pattern = re.compile(r"(ATG[ACGT]*(TAG|TAA|TGA))")
for match in re.finditer(pattern, seq):
    coding = match.group(1)
    print(coding)
```

This code is giving me output:

> ATGCCAGGCTAGCTTATTTAA

But actual output should be :

> ATGCCAGGCTAGCTTATTTAA, ATGCCAGGCTAG

what I should change in my code?

Comment: For your current example you could use 2 capturing groups https://regex101.com/r/58Unpp/1

Comment: Or to get all the variants I think this could do it `(?=(ATG[ATCG]*(?:T(?:A[AG]|GA))))(ATG[ATCG]*?(?:T(?:A[AG]|GA)))`  https://regex101.com/r/RaCUMS/1

Comment: No it fails for this **ATGCCAGGTATGTTATTGTAG** string, Output should be:
**ATGCCAGGTATGTTATTGTAG** and **ATGTTATTGTAG**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr: can't use regex for this**

---

The problem isn't greedy/non-greedy.

The problem isn't overlapping matches either: there's a solution for that ([How to find overlapping matches with a regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp))

The real problem with OP's question is, REGEX isn't designed for matches with the same start. Regex performs a linear search and stops at the first match. That's one of the reasons why it's fast. However, this prevents REGEX from supporting multiple overlapping matches starting at the same character.

See

[Regex including overlapping matches with same start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641841/regex-including-overlapping-matches-with-same-start)

for more info.

Regex isn't the be-all-end-all of pattern matching. It's in the name: *Regular* expressions are all about single-interpretation symbol sequences, and DNA tends not to fit that paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

In `r"(ATG[ACGT]*(TAG|TAA|TGA))"`, the `*` operator is "greedy". Use the non-greedy modifier, like `r"(ATG[ACGT]*?(TAG|TAA|TGA))"`, to tell the regexp to take the *shortest* matching string, not the longest.

Comment: I tried this ,but this is giving me only shortest string