# How to find all overlapping matches in regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm struggling to parse some nested formulae using the python regex module, even with `overlapped=True`.

Example (`ra` is my shorthand for 'rightarrow', i.e. implication - but it could be anything):

```
pattern = r"^\((.+) ra (.+)\)$"

re.findall(pattern, "(a ra b)", overlapped=True)
# Gives [('a', 'b')], as expected.

re.findall(pattern, "(a ra (b ra c))", overlapped=True)
# Gives [('a ra (b', 'c)')]
# Expected [('a ra (b', 'c)'), ('a', '(b ra c)')]
```

Naturally, the `('a', '(b ra c)')` result is what I'm looking for - and I was expecting `overlapped=True` to yield this.

Note: I realise this could be done using recursive regex, e.g. `(?P<formula>([abc]|\((?P<left>(?&formula)) ra (?P<right>(?&formula))\)))`, but this doesn't help in case I want the uglier `('a ra (b', 'c)')` answer too.

Comment: For a language like this, regex won't help. `overlapped=True` is only meant to extract overlapping matches that start at *different* locations in a string. You need a parser.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew - your comment led me to finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641841/regex-including-overlapping-matches-with-same-start?rq=1) equivalent question. Looks like regex is unfortunately not the tool for the job.