# Regex for combinational word matching using Python

Tags: python, regex

Trying to find multiple word match in given text.For example :

```python
text = "oracle sql"
regex = "(oracle\\ sql|sql)"
re.findall(regex,text,re.I)
```

Output actual

> oracle sql

Expected output

> oracle sql,sql

Can anyone tell me, where is problem with regex expression ?

Updated:

@jim it won't work ,if multiple overlapping comes, for example :

```
re.findall("(?=(spark|spark sql|sql))","spark sql",re.I)
```

Actual Output

> ['spark','sql']

Expected Output :

> ['spark','sql','spark sql']]

Note : In the above case if both are matched then it won't match combination of words.

Updated :

Check link : repl.it/repls/NewFaithfulMath

Comment: Which version of python are you using? I'm getting `findall() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flag'`

Comment: @jim i have removed that flag,check now

Comment: @jim python-2.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find overlapping matches with a regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp)

Comment: @UnbearableLightness My major point is how to get overlapping matched words  also how it can be duplicate.Can you give a try on this :- re.findall("(?=(spark|spark sql|sql))","spark sql",re.I)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18966698/3390419).

Comment: @UnbearableLightness see this link : repl.it/repls/NewFaithfulMath

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I have tried this also but not working with regex also

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to escape whitespace.

```
import re
text = "oracle sql"
regex = "(oracle sql|sql)"
print re.findall(regex, text, re.I)
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings.

This counts as an overlapping match.

## Returning overlapping matches

You can use a lookahead to capture the string you're looking for, but because it's technically matching on the lookahead they are not overlapping.

```
import re
text = "oracle sql"
regex = "(?=(oracle sql|sql))"
print re.findall(regex, text, re.I)
```

Output:

```
['oracle sql', 'sql']
```

[See it in action](https://repl.it/repls/ComplicatedPossibleBooleanalgebra).

The downside of this implementation is that it will only find 1 match for each word at a particular position in a string. This is due to overlapping matches.

For example `(my test|my|test)` will only find `['my test', 'test']`.

You could always use a regex replacement that will find overlapping matches too, such as [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), but this will still only find `['my test', 'test']` with the pattern `(my test|my|test)`:

```
import regex as re
text = "oracle sql"
regex = "(oracle sql|sql)"
print re.findall(regex, text, re.I, overlapped=True)
```

## Recursion

Regex will only find one match per character. It has already found the match for the first character based on "oracle sql" so you can't get a match on just `oracle`. You can't find every single one.

However... You could use a recursive function to try to match the same string with all of the items - what has already been matched.

I am not sure how performant this code will be as you could execute a lot of regex searches.

```
import re

def find_all_matches(text, items):
  regex_items = '|'.join(items)
  regex = "(?=({}))".format(regex_items)
  matches = re.findall(regex, text, re.I)
  new_items = [i for i in items if i not in matches]
  if new_items:
    new_matches = find_all_matches(text, new_items)
    return matches + new_matches
  return matches
print find_all_matches("oracle sql", ['oracle sql', 'oracle', 'sql'])
```

Output:

```
['oracle sql', 'sql', 'oracle']
```

## No regex

Lastly you could implement this without regex. Again I haven't looked at the performance of this.

```
def find_all_matches(text, items):
  return [i for i in items if i in text]

print find_all_matches("oracle sql", ['oracle sql', 'oracle', 'sql'])
```

Output:

```
['oracle sql', 'oracle', 'sql']
```

Comment: You don't need to escape whitespace.

Comment: @jim this won't work if we put  : re.findall("(?=(spark|spark sql|sql))","spark sql",re.I)

Comment: @jim Can you check in this : https://repl.it/repls/NewFaithfulMath, why not working ?

Comment: @Arpit Regex will only find one match per character. It has already found the match for the first character based on "oracle sql". You can't find every single one.

Comment: @JimWright Right now i did the same but i didn't find any suitable regex for this