# C# Regex for getting all possible matches

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to extract all the occurences of this regex

```
\d{7,8}
```

(every number that has 7 or 8 length)

The input cuould be something like

> asd123456789bbaasd

what I want is an array with:

```
["1234567", "12345678", "2345678", "23456789"]
```

all the possible occurencies of a number that has 7 or 8 lenth.

Regex.Matches works diferent, it returns all the consecutive occurencies of matches.... `["12345678"]`

Any idea?

Comment: Could you please include your [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Makes it easier to give you an accurate and succinct answer

Comment: regex is not designed for this. you have to do the permutation yourself

Comment: You'd need to match on one digit and have the rest be in a look ahead.

Comment: Something like [`(?=(\d{7}))(?=(\d{8})?)`](https://regex101.com/r/JQb0n8/1)

Comment: @elgonzo That won't work as it will miss numbers of 7 and 8 length starting from the same index. You would then need to seperate the regex to 2 steps.

Comment: @bobblebubble Very nice, you should make that an answer.

Comment: @Haytam, yes you are right. Ooops! I delete my comment with that not quite fitting answer link... :-)

Comment: Why not `3456789`? That's 7 digits also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For overlapping matches you'd need to [capture inside a lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp).

```
(?=(\d{7}))(?=(\d{8})?)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JQb0n8/1)

- `(?=(\d{7}))` the first [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) is mandatory and will capture any 7 digits
- `(?=(\d{8})?)` the second capturing group is [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) (triggered at same position)

So if there are 7 digit matches, they will be in group(1) and if 8 digit matches, in group (2). In .NET Regex you can probably use [one name for both groups](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3D%28%3F%3Cm%3E%5Cd%7B7%7D%29%29%28%3F%3D%28%3F%3Cm%3E%5Cd%7B8%7D%29%3F%29&i=asd123456789bbaasd).

For getting 7 digit matches only if there are 8 ahead, drop the `?` after `(\d{8})` [like in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/JQb0n8/2).

Comment: Get all Group 1 and 2 values, remove empty ones and it will work as expected.

Comment: Amazing! that's what I needed

Answer (score 2):

Not really what you asked for, but the end result is.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace _52228638_ExtractAllPossibleMatches
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputStr = "asd123456789bbaasd";
            foreach (string item in GetTheMatches(inputStr))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static List<string> GetTheMatches(string inputStr)
        {
            List<string> retval = new List<string>();
            int[] lengths = new int[] { 7, 8 };
            for (int i = 0; i < lengths.Length; i++)
            {
                string tmp = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(\\d{" + lengths[i] + ",})").Match(inputStr.ToString()).ToString();
                while (tmp.Length >= lengths[i])
                {
                    retval.Add(tmp.Substring(0, lengths[i]));
                    tmp = tmp.Remove(0, 1);
                }
            }
            return retval;
        }
    }
}
```