# SQL regexp - replace dots between two numbers

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

I need to change this;

```
J S49-1:7.5-190 d.
```

to this;

```
J S49-1:7,5-190 d.
```

by replacing all dots with commas, but only between numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With capture groups within `REGEXP_REPLACE`;

> ```
> select REGEXP_REPLACE('J S49-1:7.5-190 d.', '(.*\d)\.(\d.*)', '\1,\2') from dual;
> ```
>
> will return;
>
> ```
> J S49-1:7,5-190 d.
> ```

But this will not work if there are multiple occurrences of periods between digits.

**In case there are more than one occurrence of period between digits**

I was able to trigger multi replace with capture groups;

> ```
> select REGEXP_REPLACE('J S49-1:7.557.8-190 d.', '(\d)\.(\d)', '\1,\2', 1, 0) from dual;
> ```
>
> will return;
>
> ```
> J S49-1:7,557,8-190 d.
> ```

The last two parameters are; `start_position` and `nth_appearance`, to replace all occurrences, `nth_appearance` value must be `0`

But still there is a problem when two capture groups share a digit, this is due to overlapping ([same issue as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp)), and needs lookahead to resolve, but can't use it in oracle, hmmm.

**In case there are more than one occurrence of period between digits, and same digit is shared between two occurrence**

One solution would be to apply the secondary `REGEXP_REPLACE` I've shared twice, so any overlapping cases would be covered in the second run;

> ```
> select REGEXP_REPLACE(
>                  REGEXP_REPLACE('J S49-1:7.5.8.7-190 d.', '(\d)\.(\d)', '\1,\2', 1, 0), 
>                  '(\d)\.(\d)', '\1,\2', 1, 0) from dual;
> ```
>
> will be the correct result;
>
> ```
> J S49-1:7,5,8,7-190 d.
> ```

For more detail on `REGEXP_REPLACE`, check [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_replace.php)

Answer (score 2):

One way using REGEXP_SUBSTR:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('J S49-1:7.5-190 d','[^.]+',1,1)||','||REGEXP_SUBSTR('J S49-1:7.5-190 d','[^.]+',1,2) from dual;
```

Here is with regexp_replce

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('J S49-1:7.5-190 d','[.*]',',') from dual
```