# How to get overlapping regex captures in Rust?

Tags: regex, rust

I'm trying to match the two characters after a specific character. The trailing values may contain the specified character, which is ok, but I also need to capture that specified character as the beginning of the next capture group.

This code should illustrate what I mean:

```rust
extern crate regex;
use regex::Regex;


pub fn main() {
    let re = Regex::new("(a..)").unwrap();
    let st = String::from("aba34jf baacdaab");
    println!("String to match: {}", st);

    for cap in re.captures_iter(&st) {
        println!("{}", cap[1].to_string());
        // Prints "aba" and "aac",
        // Should print "aba", "a34", "aac", "acd", "aab"
    }
}
```

How do I get overlapping captures without using look around (which the regex crate doesn't support in Rust)?  Is there something similar to what is in Python ([as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp/18966698#18966698)) but in Rust?

**Edit:**

Using onig as BurntSushi5 suggested, we get the following:

```rust
extern crate onig;
use onig::*;

pub fn main() {
    let re = Regex::new("(?=(a.{2}))").unwrap();
    let st = String::from("aba34jf baacdaab");
    println!("String to match: {}", st);

    for ch in re.find_iter(&st) {
        print!("{} ", &st[ch.0..=ch.1+2]);
        // aba a34 aac acd aab, as it should.
        // but we have to know how long the capture is.
    }
    println!("");
}
```

Now the problem with this is that you have to know how long the regex is, because the look ahead group doesn't capture. Is there a way to get the look ahead regex captured without knowing the length beforehand? How would we print it out if we had something like `(?=(a.+))` as the regex?

Comment: The regex crate says look around isn't supported, so I didn't even try it.  I get the error: `error: look-around, including look-ahead and look-behind, is not supported`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Your only recourse is to either find a different approach entirely, or use a different regex engine that supports look-around like [`onig`](https://crates.io/crates/onig) or [`pcre2`](https://crates.io/crates/pcre2).

Comment: It's not possible to get the offset of the first match, then start the next search one codepoint in, repeating until no more matches?

Comment: Yeah I guess that to me falls under "different approach." I don't think it will work in all cases. When I get a chance I can update my answer to include some code for that.

Comment: I used the onig binding and the look-ahead method works now. However, this particular method requires knowing how long the capture will be because we can't capture the part inside the look-ahead part. Do you know if there's an option to turn that on? I can't find documentation for that at all.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, unfortunately not regex though:

```rust
pub fn main() {
    print_char_matches ("aba34jf baacdaab", 'a', 2);
    //aba a34 aac acd aab, as it should.
}

pub fn print_char_matches( st:&str, char_match:char, match_length:usize ) {
    let chars:Vec<_> = st.char_indices().collect();

    println!("String to match: {}", st);

    for i in 0..chars.len()-match_length {
        if chars[i].1 == char_match {
            for j in 0..=match_length {
                print!("{}", chars[i+j].1);
            }
            print!(" ");
        }
    }
    println!("");
}
```

This is a bit more generalizable, ASCII only.  Matches the character provided and the specified number of digits after the match.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your regex to only match at the start of the string by prefixing `^` and then iterate over the characters to let your search start at each character. This will make sure that you get all overlapping matches.

```rust
extern crate regex;
use regex::Regex;


pub fn main() {
    let re = Regex::new("^(a..)").unwrap();
    let st = String::from("aba34jf baacdaab");
    println!("String to match: {}", st);

    for cap in st.char_indices().filter_map(|(i,_)| re.captures(&st[i..]))  {
        println!("{}", cap[1].to_string());
        // Prints "aba", "a34", "aac", "acd", "aab"
    }
}
```