# Count overlapping occurrences of substring in strings in polars DataFrame

Tags: python, python-polars

What is the best way to count the number of overlapping occurrences of a given substring in strings stored in  a column of polars DataFrame?

Polars API provides `polars.Expr.str.count_matches` that counts all successive non-overlapping regex matches.
With DaTaFrame:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"foo": ["aaaaa", "aabaa", "aaaab"]})
```

the result of such counting

```
df.with_columns(pl.col("foo").str.count_matches("aa"))
```

is polars DataFrame filled with [2,2,2]. How to get the counts of overlapping occurrences? The expected result in this case is polars DataFrame filled with [4,2,3].

Comment: I’m not sure it’s possible. Polars documentation refers to ´regex crate´being used for reg expressions. I’m on my phone now so cannot try polars, but I’ve tried uding look ahead regexp in Rust and i got ‘look-around, including look-ahead and look-behind, is not supported’ error.

Comment: According to another SO answer, it looks like the Regex crate does not support this functionality and one would need to incorporate another crate instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57497045/how-to-get-overlapping-regex-captures-in-rust

Answer (score 2):

There does not appear to be an easy way to do this with the current API.

You can implement the logic manually, some possible approaches in case they are of use:

#### [`.rolling()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.rolling.html#polars.DataFrame.rolling)

```py
needle = "aa"

(df.with_row_index()
   .with_columns(pl.col("foo").str.split(""))
   .explode("foo")
   .rolling(by="index", index_column=pl.int_range(pl.len()), period=f"{len(needle)}i")
   .agg(pl.col("foo").str.concat("") == needle)
   .group_by("index", maintain_order=True)
   .agg(pl.col("foo").sum())
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬─────┐
│ index ┆ foo │
│ ---   ┆ --- │
│ u32   ┆ u32 │
╞═══════╪═════╡
│ 0     ┆ 4   │
│ 1     ┆ 2   │
│ 2     ┆ 3   │
└───────┴─────┘
```

#### `.int_ranges()` + `.str.slice()`

```py
needle = "aa"

(df.with_columns(offset = pl.int_ranges(pl.col("foo").str.len_chars()))
   .with_row_index()
   .explode("offset")
   .group_by("index", maintain_order=True)
   .agg(
      (pl.col("foo").str.slice("offset", len(needle)) == needle).sum()
   )
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬─────┐
│ index ┆ foo │
│ ---   ┆ --- │
│ u32   ┆ u32 │
╞═══════╪═════╡
│ 0     ┆ 4   │
│ 1     ┆ 2   │
│ 2     ┆ 3   │
└───────┴─────┘
```

#### [`.cumulative_eval()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cumulative_eval.html#polars-expr-cumulative-eval)

Perhaps the "easiest to write" but least efficient.

```py
needle = "aa"

df.with_columns(count = 
   pl.col("foo").str.explode()
     .cumulative_eval(pl.element().tail(len(needle)).str.concat("") == needle).sum()
     .over(pl.int_range(pl.len()))
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ foo   ┆ count │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ u32   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ aaaaa ┆ 4     │
│ aabaa ┆ 2     │
│ aaaab ┆ 3     │
└───────┴───────┘
```

#### [duckdb](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/overview.html)

DuckDB can read/write dataframes, for comparison sake a couple of approaches:

```py
duckdb.sql("""
from df
select
   *,   
   list_sum([
      (foo[idx:idx + len('aa') - 1] == 'aa')::int 
      for idx in range(1, foo.len())
   ]) count1,  
   len(range(1, len(foo)).filter(
      idx -> foo[idx:idx + len('aa') - 1] == 'aa')
   ) count2
""").pl()
```

```py
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬────────┬────────┐
│ foo   ┆ count1 ┆ count2 │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ str   ┆ f64    ┆ i64    │
╞═══════╪════════╪════════╡
│ aaaaa ┆ 4.0    ┆ 4      │
│ aabaa ┆ 2.0    ┆ 2      │
│ aaaab ┆ 3.0    ┆ 3      │
└───────┴────────┴────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to approach this problem is to group/partition your strings into chunks of size 2 and operate on those chunks. The approach I have taken here requires 2 passes on the data since I pre-evaluate the `most_chars` variable.

```py
import polars as pl
from polars import col, selectors as cs

df = pl.DataFrame({"foo": ["aaaaa", "aabaa", "aaaab"]})
most_chars = df.select(col('foo').str.len_chars().max()).item()

print(
    df.select(
        col('foo').str.slice(i, 2).alias(str(i)) for i in range(most_chars-1)
    )
    .select(
        df, count=pl.sum_horizontal(cs.all().str.count_matches('aa'))
    )
)
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ foo   ┆ count │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ u32   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ aaaaa ┆ 4     │
│ aabaa ┆ 2     │
│ aaaab ┆ 3     │
└───────┴───────┘
```