# Combine in an efficient way regex python

Tags: python, regex, optimization, python-re, findall

#### Setup

I create dynamically a list of regex, namely `regex_list`.
Each regex in the list does for sure at least one match on the text to which is applied.
It may happens that some regex in the list are equals.

```py
regex_list = []
for f in foo: # foo is a list of strings e.g. foo = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo1', ...]
    # f is a valid expression to be used inside the regex
    regex_list.append(f'[^.]*?{f}[^.]*\.')

regex = re.compile('|'.join(regex_list), flags=re.DOTALL)
result = re.findall(regex, text)
```

#### Problem

Since

1. some regex in `regex_list` may be equals
2. regex in `regex_list` are combined together with the OR operator

for the regex for which exists another copy in the list, only the first match in the text is captured.

#### Question

A workaround could be to apply each regex individually with a for-loop, but it is very slow.

Is there a good way to combine regex and make them match everything possible?

Comment: What have you got inside `foo`? A couple of examples would do. However, it seems you just have independent regexps that need to be executed one by one on a text.

Comment: ```foo``` is a list of strings.
e.g. ```foo = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo1', ...]```

Comment: Like `['John', 'John Doe', 'John Doe Junior']`?

Comment: Yes, I've added an example

Comment: Ok, you will be able to use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42789508/3832970). Probably, with [overlapping regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp), you can get closer. However, `[^.]*?{f}[^.]*\.` pattern means the `[^.]` might just eat any other potential matches. You will need to post-process matches, I am afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casually discovered that applying each regex individually in a for-loop is very slow using the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), while it's surprisingly faster using the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex).