# How to grep/perl/awk overlapping regex

Tags: regex, perl, awk, grep, overlapping

Trying to pipe a string into a grep/perl regex to pull out overlapping matches. Currently, the results only appear to pull out sequential matches without any "lookback":

Attempt using egrep (both on GNU and BSD):

```
$ echo "bob mary mike bill kim jim john" | egrep -io "[a-z]+ [a-z]+"
bob mary
mike bill
kim jim
```

Attempt using perl style grep (-P):

```
$ echo "bob mary mike bill kim jim john" | grep -oP "()[a-z]+ [a-z]+"
bob mary
mike bill
kim jim
```

Attempt using awk showing only the first match:

```
$ echo "bob mary mike bill kim jim john" | awk 'match($0, /[a-z]+ [a-z]+/) {print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}'
bob mary
```

The overlapping results I'd like to see from a simple working bash pipe command are:

```
bob mary
mary mike
mike bill
bill kim
kim jim
jim john
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out "lookahead assertions." You can combine these with global (/g) option and a capture group inside the assertion to retrieve the matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookahead is your friend here

```
echo "bob mary mike bill kim jim john" | 
    perl -wnE'say "$1 $2" while /(\w+)\s+(?=(\w+))/g'
```

---

The point is that lookahead, as a "zero-width assertion," doesn't consume anything -- while it still allows us to capture a pattern in it.

So as the regex engine matches a word and spaces (`(\w+)\s+`), gobbling them up, it then stops there and "looks ahead," merely to "assert" that the sought pattern is there; it doesn't move from its spot between the last space and the next `\w`, doesn't "consume" that next word, as they say.

It is nice though that we can also capture that pattern that is "seen," even tough it's not consumed! So we get our `$1` and `$2`, two words.

Then, because of `/g` modifier, the engine moves on, to find another word+spaces, with yet another word following.  That next word is the one our lookahead spotted -- so now that one is consumed, and yet next one "looked" for (and captured). Etc.

See [Lookahead and lookbehind assertions in perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Perl one-liners below, which avoid the lookahead (which can still be your friend):
For whitespace-delimited words:

```
echo "bob mary mike bill kim jim john" | perl -lane 'print "$F[$_] $F[$_+1]" for 0..($#F-1);'
```

For words defined as `\w+` in Perl, delimited by the non-word characters `\W+`:

```
echo "bob.mary,mike'bill kim jim john" | perl -F'/\W+/' -lane 'print "$F[$_] $F[$_+1]" for 0..($#F-1);'
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F'/\W+/'` : Split into `@F` on `\W+` (one or more non-word characters), rather than on whitespace.

`$#F` : the last index of the array `@F`, into which the input line is split.
`0..($#F-1)` : the range of indexes (numbers), from the first (`0`) to the penultimate (`$#F-1`) index of the array `@F`.
`$F[$_]` and `$F[$_+1]`: two consecutive elements of the array `@F`, with indexes `$_` and `$_+1`, respectively.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `awk`

```sh
awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i,$(i+1)}' <<< 'bob mary mike bill kim jim john'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/ZOP7Ul). This solution iterates over all whitespace-separated fields and prints current field (`$i`) + field separator (a space here) + the subsequent field value (`$(i+1)`).

Or, another `perl` solution that uses a [very common technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp) to capture the overlapping pattern inside a positive lookahead:

```sh
perl -lane 'while (/(?=\b(\p{L}+\s+\p{L}+))/g) {print $1}' <<< 'bob mary mike bill kim jim john'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/a46JXB). *Details*:

- `(?=` - start of a positive lookahead

  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `(\p{L}+\s+\p{L}+)` - capturing group 1: one or more letters, one or more whitespaces, one or more letters
- `)` - end of the lookahead.

Here, only Group 1 values are printed (`{print $1}`).

**Performance consideration**

As for Perl solutions here, mine turns out the slowest, and Timur's the fastest, however, `awk` solution turns out to be faster than any Perl solutions. Results:

```sh
# ./wiktor_awk.sh

real    0m17.069s
user    0m12.264s
sys     0m5.314s

# ./timur_perl.sh

real    0m18.201s
user    0m15.612s
sys     0m6.139s

# ./zdim.sh

real    0m23.559s
user    0m19.883s
sys     0m7.359s

# ./wiktor_perl.sh

real    2m12.528s
user    1m52.857s
sys     0m20.201s
```

Note I created *.sh files for each solution like

```sh
#!/bin/bash
N=10000
time(
 for i in $(seq 1 $N); do
   <SOLUTION_HERE> &>/dev/null;
done)
```

and ran `for f in *.sh; do chmod +x "$f"; done` (borrowed from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/915134/1170536)).