# Python - Regex findall extract all patterns that may be substring of one another

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have a list of keywords and want to extract all the keywords that can be found in a document. One keyword may be the substring of another keyword. I tried to extract with `re.findall` function, but what I get is either one keyword or the substring of the keyword. If 'A' and 'A B' are the keywords, I want to extract both.

Take one simplified case as an example:

The document is `"A B C D"`. The keyword is `"A", "B", "A B"`. The output of my regex pattern is like:

```py
string = "A B C D"
regex = 'A\ B|A|B'
re.findall(regex, string)
>>> ['A B']
```

```py
string = "A B C D"
regex = 'A|B|A\ B'
re.findall(regex, string)
>>> ['A', 'B']
```

The expected output is

```
['A', 'B', 'A B']
```

**Updated:**
Similar post suggested to use [new Python regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) to solve the overlapped example.

```py
import regex as re
re.findall(r'A\\ B|B\\ C', 'A B C', overlapped=True)
>>> ['A B', 'B C']
```

However the solution can not solve the case that one pattern is a substring of another pattern:

```py
import regex as re
re.findall(r'A\\ B|A', 'A B C', overlapped=True)
>>> ['A B']
```

expected:

```
>>> ['A B', 'A']
```

PS:
To be more specific, my regex pattern is like `"(?<!\w)A\\ B(?!\w)|(?<!\w)A(?!\w)"` but I think the simplified case is more clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find overlapping matches with a regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp)

Comment: Or perhaps this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches

Comment: @Nick Thanks for your reply! The situation is quite similar but it does not fully solve my case. For example adding overlapped=True to regex module works for `re.findall(r'A\\ B|B\\ C', 'A B C', overlapped=True)` but not for `re.findall(r'A|A\\ B', 'A B C', overlapped=True)`. When the keyword is a substring of another keyword, regex for this method can not extract all the keywords.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I suggest you edit the question to make it clear as to why it is different from the duplicates I proposed. Then I'll remove my close vote.

Comment: Hi @Nick, I’ve updated the question. Thanks a lot for all the suggestions.

Comment: I think you probably will need to iterate over your keywords e.g. https://ideone.com/Fpxuz3

Comment: Hi @Nick, yeah I think you are right. Could you make this comment as an answer so that I can accept the answer? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the situation where one keyword is a substring of another, you will need to iterate over your keywords as matching using regex will always pick one or the other (most modules such as `re` pick the first match in the alternation - see [here](https://regex101.com/r/QGUPgG/1)) at a given point in the string, but never both. You could iterate over the keywords to ensure you find all matches using code like this:

```py
import re
 
string = "A B C D"
keys = ["A", "B", "A B"]
 
matches = []
for k in keys:
    matches += re.findall(re.escape(k), string)
 
print(matches)
```

Output

```
['A', 'B', 'A B']
```

[Demo on ideone](https://ideone.com/Fpxuz3)

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will find 3 matches in the string " A B ".
We look for a space with a lookback for `\bA` and a lookahead for `B\b`. The problem is that the second match returns the space  and not the string `A B`.
You would have to replace a space with a `A B`

```
(\bA\b)|((?<=(\bA)) (?=B\b))|(\bB\b)
```

Comment: Hi @Kendle, yeah the pattern can extract all the matches. But I'm afraid it’s hard to expand to other patterns, like other keywords ‘A B C’, ‘A B’, ‘B C’, ‘C D’. I think it’s almost impossible to implement all the patterns manually or with a simple rule.