# Need to find all sets of 2 capital words

Tags: regex

Hello I need to find all sets of 2 capital words : So far I have:

```
([A-Z][a-z]+\s?){2}
```

But it does not work always.
For Example with the string:

```
Expedition Runic Monster Markers
```

I expect to get :

1. Expedition Runic
2. Runic Monster
3. Monster Markers

I only get 1 and 3. But I also want to get 2. I'm really stuck here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! You can [capture inside a lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp) -> [sample](https://regex101.com/r/khaY5y/2)

Answer (score 3):

Overlapping matches need to be [captured inside a lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp).

```
\b(?=((?:[A-Z][a-z]+\s?\b){2}))
```

[See this demo at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7kII2c/1) (further added [`\b` word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html))

If you are on Python, there is [PyPI regex with `overlapped=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18966891/5527985).

Comment: This solved it for me and thanks for the demo resource. I'm using Java this worked as it, Thanks for the quick answer!