# Java regex : How to reuse a consumed character in pattern matching?

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to reuse a consumed character of the source in pattern matching?

For example, suppose I want to find a pattern with regex expression `(a+b+|b+a+)`
i.e. more than one a followed by more than one b OR vice versa.

Suppose the input is `aaaabbbaaaaab`

Then the output using regex would be `aaaabbb` and `aaaaab`

How can I get the output to be

```
aaaabbb
bbbaaaaa
aaaaab
```

Comment: You dont reconsume a character. You would have to modify the reg ex to match as you want.

Comment: This should be able to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320448/overlapping-matches-in-regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way

```
String data = "aaaabbbaaaaab";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?=(a+b+|b+a+))(^|(?<=a)b|(?<=b)a)").matcher(data);
while(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

This regex uses [look around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms and will find `(a+b+|b+a+)` that

- exists at start `^` of the input
- starts with `b` that is predicted by `a`
- starts with `a` that is predicted by `b`.

Output:

```
aaaabbb
bbbaaaaa
aaaaab
```

---

> Is `^` essentially needed in this regular expression?

Yes, without `^` this regex wouldn't capture `aaaabbb` placed at start of input.

If I wouldn't add `(^|(?<=a)b|(?<=b)a)` after `(?=(a+b+|b+a+))` this regex would match

```
aaaabbb
aaabbb
aabbb
abbb
bbbaaaaa
bbaaaaa
baaaaa
aaaaab
aaaab
aaab
aab
ab
```

so I needed to limit this results to only these that starts with `a` that has `b` before it (but not include `b` in match - so look behind was perfect for that) and `b` that is predicted by `a`.

But lets not forget about `a` or `b` that are placed at start of the string and are not predicted by anything. To include them we can use `^`.

---

Maybe it will be easier to show this idea with this regex

`(?=(a+b+|b+a+))((?<=^|a)b|(?<=^|b)a)`.

- `(?<=^|a)b` will match `b` that is placed at start of string, or has `a` before it
- `(?<=^|b)a` will match `a` that is placed at start of string, or has `b` before it

Comment: Thank You very much:). Its a really clear answer. I had a look over at regex buddy, but still have some confusions because I'm really new to regex. In the regex expression could you please further explain a bit of what the ^ means? 

Thank you again for the great answer:).

Comment: @dgun `^` is [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) that matches beginning of String.

Comment: Is ^ essentially needed in this regular expression? Why is that?
(Sorry if that's stupid, I'm just curious:))

Comment: @dgun Check my edited answer. If there are things that you still don't understand just ask.

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate this with lookbehind:

```
((?<=a)b+|(?<=b)a+)
```

This outputs

```
bbb aaaaa b
```