# R why is gregexpr not returning all occurrences of a regex pattern?

Tags: r

I have the following string:

```
FFDEFFDFFDCFFDDFFAAF
```

and the following regex pattern:

```
FF..FF
```

Running gregexpr will result in the following:

```
gregexpr('FF..FF','FFDEFFDFFDCFFDDFFAAF')

[[1]]
[1] 1 8
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 6 6
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

But there is one match missing, as there are three occurrences of the pattern:

```
FFDEFFDFFDCFFDDFFAAF
FF..FF ||  ||  || 
       FF..FF  ||
           FF..FF
```

Any idea why is this happening and how to resolve this?

Comment: Regex doesn't do overlapping patterns, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/320448/903061) [or here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11430863/903061) for ways to get around this with lookahead.

Comment: Thanks, with perl=TRUE i can use lookahead as you suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need a look ahead expression which you can do with a perl regex:

```
gregexpr("(?=FF..FF)", "FFDEFFDFFDCFFDDFFAAF", perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what i was missing after Gregor comment... The perl=TRUE