# Finding all occurrences of alternating digits using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, string

I would like to find all alternating digits in a string using regular expressions. An alternating digit is defined as two equal digits having a digit in between; for example, 1212 contains 2 alternations (121 and 212) and 1111 contains 2 alternations as well (111 and 111). I have the following regular expression code:

```
s = "1212"
re.findall(r'(\d)(?:\d)(\1)+', s)
```

This works for strings like "121656", but not "1212". This is a problem to do with overlapping matches I think. How can I deal with that?

Comment: Specific answer given by @vks; also see answer to similar question @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/320478/43774.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
(?=((\d)\d\2))
```

Use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to get all overlapping matches. Use `re.findall` and get the first element from the tuple. See the demo:

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/54

Comment: To match the captures of his question, I'd use `(\d)(?=(?:\d)(\1))`.

Comment: @Roy i guess he wants `121 and 212` rather than  `1 or 2`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a lookahead to allow for overlapping matches:

```
r'(\d)(?=(\d)\1)'
```

To reconstruct full matches from this:

```
matches = re.findall(r'(\d)(?=(\d)\1)', s)
[a + b + a for a, b in matches]
```

Also, to avoid other Unicode digits like ١ from being matched (assuming you don’t want them), you should use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.

Answer (score 3):

With the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) you don't have to use a trick to get overlapped matches since there's a flag to obtain them:

```
import regex
res = [x.group(0) for x in regex.finditer(r'(\d)\d\1', s, overlapped=True)]
```

if s contains only digits, you can do this too:

```
res = [s[i-2:i+1] for i in range(2, len(s)) if s[i]==s[i-2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

A non regex approach if you string is made up of just digits:

```
from itertools import islice as isl, izip

s = "121231132124123"
out = [a + b + c for a, b, c in zip(isl(s, 0, None), isl(s, 1, None), isl(s, 2, None)) if a == c]
```

Output:

```
['121', '212', '212']
```

It is actually a nice bit faster than a regex approach.