# Regex - Find multiple matches

Tags: c#, regex

I have following `1010159552597` and I would like to find the numbers that start with 10, followed by 1 or 0 and ending with 7 digits. I use following RegEx to search

```
(10[01][0-9]{7})
```

Following result is given: `1010159552`

But I also would have expected the following: `1015955259`

How can I manage to get both results?

Thanks

Comment: So do you have a list of numbers or a big string with one long number in it or is this a user input and you just want to test if the typed number matches?  What about decimals `101.007`?

Comment: Do you need to return whether a given number is valid or not based out of the regex expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions *consume* characters and don't go back over previous matches. A way around this is to use zero-length assertions (see code below) to capture what you want.

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/flHGhz/1)

```
(?=(10[01]\d{7}))
```

Results are in capture group 1:

- `1010159552`
- `1015955259`

---

### Explanation

- `(?=(10[01]\d{7}))` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches

  - `(10[01]\d{7})` Capture your original expression into capture group 1

Comment: *Every component* of a regex pattern is an "assertion"

Answer (score 0):

You're right in that your expectation does match your regex, however, it will try to find the first instance of that match.

In your case the first term is:

10 - 1 - 0159552

so this is the solution given.

Since your results are overlapping, you might want to check out this article.

[Overlapping matches in Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320448/overlapping-matches-in-regex/321391)