# How to make end of one match is start of other

Tags: regex

Why does the pattern `A[^A]+A` only match once in `AWERTYUIOPAZXCA`?

Should be: `AWERTYUIOPA` and `AZXCA`.

https://regex101.com/r/Fd13U4/1

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320448/overlapping-matches-in-regex/321391

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex matches the string

```
AWERTYUIOPAZXCA
|---------| 
A[^A]+    A
```

This is the only pattern in that string.

The remaining string doesn't match anymore, because it doesn't begin with `A`:

```
ZXCA
|
A...
```

If you change the string to: `AWERTYUIOPAAZXCA` it will match twice:

```
AWERTYUIOPAAZXC      A
|---------||---------|
A[^A]+    AA[^A]+    A
```

If you use a positive lookahead, you can assure to only match strings that end with an `A`:

```
((A[^A]+)(?=A))
```

This will give you `AWERTYUIOP` and `AZXC` - you need to tweak the regex if you want to capture the last character but it doesn't capture if the string/character (`A`) is not present.