# Regex : matches all occurences of repeating pattern including overlaps one after each other

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I extract the two overlapping matches here?

```js
console.log(', , ,'.match(/,\s+,/g));
```

First match:

```
      ', , ,'
       ^ ^
from --+ |
to ------+
```

Second match:

```
      ', , ,'
         ^ ^
from ----+ |
to --------+
```

- For the input `", ,"` it should match once
- For the input `", , ,"` it should match twice
- For the input `", , , ,"` it should match thrice

Comment: What is the exact output you want to achieve?

Comment: I thought I made it pretty simple ... I want to have all matches of a recurring pattern. So `, ,` should matche once, `, , ,` twice, `, , , ,` thrice, etc.

Comment: Other potential duplicate targets: [How to use regex to find all overlapping matches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5616822), [Overlapping matches in Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/320448).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to, instead of matching the comma directly, use a "positive lookahead" to check for a `,` past the right edge of the match.

That way the next group can also match the `,`:

```js
console.log(', , ,'.match(/,\s+(?=,)/g));
```

Comment: Thank, you, that's almost what I need ! Is it possible to include the ending comma in the result ?

Comment: why not also positive lookbehind? `/(?<=,)\s+(?=,)/g`

Comment: @DiegoD combination of both gives only the space between the commas, not the commas included. Altough this is exactly what I am aiming for in my code (so thank you), is it possible to include the commas in the result ?

Comment: @MGX yes indeed lookahead and lookbehind are zero-length assertions. I limited my contribution to a small comment also for that reason. I actually don't know the best way to achieve that using regex only

Comment: @MGX No, regex matches can not overlap so it is impossible to include both commas. You can include either the left or the right comma though depending on if you use a lookahead or a lookbehind

Comment: I see, thank you both for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

One way to get overlapping matches is to use a lookahead with a capturing group:

```js
subject = '1-2-3-4'
re = /(?=(\d-\d))/g

console.log([...subject.matchAll(re)].map(m => m[1]))
```

Comment: Seems to do the work, is there a way to do it without relying on the underlying language used ? (So only with a regex modification) ?

Answer (score -3):

```js
console.log(', , ,'.match(/,\s{1,},/g));
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on your answer?

Comment: please add an explanation that explains how your answer differs from the other answers or how it would solve the issue.